# String initialization fails

Tags: c++, initialization

This is my program. The output should be a sequence of 'a' chars, but for some reason it's not. Why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int NAME_LENGTH = 16;

struct Record {
    char hotel_name[NAME_LENGTH];
};

int main() {
    int amount = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        Record * elementToBeAdded = new Record;
        for (int j = 0; j < NAME_LENGTH; j++)     
            elementToBeAdded->hotel_name[i] = 'a';
        elementToBeAdded->hotel_name[NAME_LENGTH-1] = '\0';
        cout << "string-" << elementToBeAdded->hotel_name << "-\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for including a short, complete testcase. See http://sscce.org

Answer (score 6):

Because you have a typo in

```
        elementToBeAdded->hotel_name[i] = 'a';
```

You mean j, not i.

Answer (score 2):

Your innermost loop is using `i` when it surely intends to use `j`:

```
elementToBeAdded->hotel_name[i] = 'a';
```

as a result, you'll never set the zeroth element of `Record` #1's `char[]`, nor the one-th element of `Record` #2's, etc. That means that every time through the outermost loop except the first, the very first `char` in the hotel name will remain uninitialized, very possibly `\0`.

Also, the `Record` objects you're creating are never being deleted, so this is leaking memory at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

`elementToBeAdded->hotel_name[i] = 'a';`

should be

`elementToBeAdded->hotel_name[j] = 'a';`

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a mis-spelling in your source code above:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < NAME_LENGTH; j++)     
  elementToBeAdded->hotel_name[i] = 'a';
```

the index should be [j] here.

Answer (score 0):

You got `i` and `j` mixed up:

```
for (int j = 0; j < NAME_LENGTH; j++)     
    elementToBeAdded->hotel_name[i] = 'a'; //<-- should be j here
```

You're also leaking memory, you should `delete elementToBeAdded;` at the end of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you know the mistake, use [`std::fill_n`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill_n/) instead which is in algorithm header.

```
#include <algorithm>

// .....

for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {         

   Record * elementToBeAdded = new Record;
   std::fill_n( elementToBeAdded->hotel_name, NAME_LENGTH-2, 'a' );
   elementToBeAdded->hotel_name[NAME_LENGTH-1] = '\0';         

   cout << "string-" << elementToBeAdded->hotel_name << "-\n\n";
   delete  elementToBeAdded;
}
```